# Where in the US is the best geographic location to host servers for the UK/Europe market?

Tags: hosting, vps

We would like to keep our hosting in the US.

But for European traffic, where is the best location for ping/response times? (East Coast, West Coast, Central etc)

Comment: I am aware of the trans-Atlantic Frankfurt-Washington link, which often shows up in Europe-to-US traceroutes. But that is not really an answer, thus adding as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

East coast is definitely best, latency to the rest of the US shouldn't exceed 40ms, and you can get to most of Europe for not much more.

Answer (score 1):

The East Coast is good. There are plenty of well-connected facilities in New Jersey and Manhattan that serve the financial industry with links to the UK and Europe.